# Cascade of outer joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As a schematic example, I have 3 tables that I desire to join, A,B,C where A to B is joined via an outer join and B to C is potentially joined via an inner join. In this constellation, I have to write two outer joins to get data if the first join does not have a match A-B in a line:

```
SELECT [fields] FROM
       A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       B ON [a.field]=[b.field] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       C ON [b.field]=[c.field]
```

It seems to me logically that I have to write the second statement as an outer join. However I'm curious if there is a possiblity to set brackets for the join scope to signal that the second join should only used if the first inner join has found matching data for A-B. Something like:

```
SELECT [fields] FROM
       A
      (LEFT OUTER JOIN
       B ON [a.field]=[b.field] 
       INNER JOIN
       C ON [b.field]=[c.field]
       )
```

I have played around a little but not found a possiblity to set brackets. The only way I have found to make this working is with a sub-query. Is this the only way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a syntax for that case.

```
SELECT fields
FROM A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    B INNER JOIN C ON b.field = c.field
  ) ON a.field = b.field
```

The parentheses are optional, and the result is the same without them, being equivalent to the result of

```
SELECT fields
FROM A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON a.field = b.field
  LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON b.field = c.field
```

Comment: What?! The second query is equivalent of the first one? This is two regular outer joins, and is the same as what OP mentioned in his question. I guess you mean: `SELECT fields FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B INNER JOIN C ON b.field = c.field ON a.field = b.field`

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: No, I didn't say the two queries in this answer are equivalent, I only said their *results* would be equivalent. The second query is from the original post, yes. I slightly reformatted it to make it easier to compare the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could perform it as follows

```
SELECT Fields 
FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Fields
                 FROM TableB b
                 INNER JOIN TableC c ON b.Field = c.Field) x on a.Field = x.Fi
```

eld

Not too sure if there would be any performance benefit to this without testing it out though.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is also the solution I have found (and sometimes use). I called it in my post "sub-query". However I'm looking forward for something more integrated. But probably it does not exist...

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd way would be with a subquery as per Jon Bridges' answer

However, they are the same semantically.

A [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) could be used if you have a complex subquery

```
;WITH BjoinC AS
(
    SELECT Fields
    FROM TableB b
    INNER JOIN
    TableC c ON b.Field = c.Field
)
SELECT [fields] FROM
       A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       BjoinC ON ...
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. Added the msdn link for CTEs to your post. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

What About something like:

```
SELECT [fields] 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT [fields]
            FROM B
            LEFT JOIN C ON b.field = c.field
          ) on a.field = b.field
```